# How to join several big arrays into one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-management, cpu-usage

I'm fairly new to python, and I have 5 big arrays A,B,C,D,E with shapes:

```
((1000000, 8), (1000000, 7), (1000000, 13840), (1000000, 204), (1000000, 3))
```

dtypes:

```
(dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'))
```

Now i would like to join them all into a single array with a shape of

```
(1000000, 8+7+13840+204+3) = (1000000, 14062)
```

I have tried all possible ways (hstack/concate),

```
data_feature = np.concatenate((A,B,C,D,E), axis=1)
data_feature = np.hstack([A,B,C,D,E])
data_feature = np.hstack((A,B,C,D,E))
data_feature = np.column_stack([A,B,C,D,E])
```

but it all kills my system (Macbook Pro 2017/ 2.8GHz Intel Core i7/16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3), I think this could be a kernel problem, any suggestions that i can do this with my computer?

Comment: `1000000 * 13840 * 8 ~ 103 GB` How does this not already croak on input #3?

Comment: Do you need them all in memory at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given 64-bit (8 byte) values, you are trying to process:

```
1000000 * 14062 * 8 * 2 = 224'992'000'000 bytes
```

The 2 on the end is because you have inputs plus equal-size outputs.

That is 209 GiB of data.  You have 16 GiB of RAM.  It is not feasible.  You'll need to think harder about how you're processing your data, and how you can reduce it by a factor of 10.  Or buy a machine with 192 GiB of RAM (which is very possible these days, just not on a laptop).